# Circle the Dot Solution

Tags: game-theory

I have been playing the game [Circle the Dot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.circlethedot) on my phone.  For those who don't want to click the link, the game is played on a hexagonal array.  At the beginning, a blue dot spawns in one of the hexagons.  Several other orange dots spawn in as well.  The player makes a move, and then the dot makes a move.  The player can put another orange dot anywhere on the array.  Then the dot moves.  It can move to any adjacent hexagon not covered by an orange dot.  Its goal is to escape off the side of the board.  The player's job is to stop this.  I recommend you download and try it.  The game is very similar to Hex, and I have been using my knowledge of hex strategy to try and catch the blue dot.  However, very often I fail.  Does anyone know if the game is always winnable by the player?  What's the strategy?  If not, is there some size grid so that it is?

Comment: There may be many reasons other than being lazy for not clicking a link. Some people don't blindly trust links. Another reason may be that the link stops working (the app may be taken down, for instance). So don't say it's because we're lazy.

Comment: This is a classic graph theory problem; you consider the playfield as an undirected graph and placing an orange dot is equivalent to removing an edge from the graph. Here's a fun place to work on the problem yourself: https://www.codingame.com/training/medium/skynet-revolution-episode-1